# Given the initial condition and ODE

Tags: calculus, integration

$\newcommand{\diff}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$
I was given the following differential equation:

$$\begin{align}\diff&=4(x^2+1)\\ \frac{dx}{1+x^2}&= 4dt \\ \arctan(x)&=4t+C\end{align}$$
The initial condition is the following:
$$x(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$$

I did the following substitution to get the following:
\begin{align}\arctan(x)&=4t+C \\ \frac{\pi}{4}&=4(\frac{\pi}4)+C \\ C&=-\frac{3\pi}4\end{align}
My question is what if the constant is on the other side? I get the following:
$$\frac{\pi}4+C=\pi$$
$$C=\frac{3\pi}4$$

The first constant the works the other one doesn't is there a specific reason why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Omielan already answered. In any case, to avoid this "ambiguity" you can use definite integration: you found $dx/(1+x^2) = 4dt$, so integrating
$$\int_1^x \frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\int_{\pi/4}^t 4\,ds,$$
which gives $\arctan x - \pi/4 = 4t-\pi$.

Comment: That is smart and cool. +1 How did you know you could that? Is the FTC part of it? Because I see the dummy variable substitutions.

Comment: The substitution of variables is just to avoid redundancy and make everything easier to read. Yes it is basically the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $C$ is basically an *arbitrary* constant, which you determine from initial conditions, *including* how it's used in the equation, so it doesn't have any particular fixed value. In particular, note using a "$C$" on the left side would not be the same as the "$C$" used on the right side. If you check, you can move a $C$ to the other side to have it become $-C$ (e.g., $\arctan(x) = 4t + C \implies \arctan(x) - C = 4t$). This is why your two determined $C$ values only differ in sign, i.e., between $C = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$ when the $C$ is on the right side and $C = \frac{3\pi}{4}$ when it's on the left side.