# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^3}{9-x^4}dx$ using u substitution and the log identity for integrating $x^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.3

Evaluate $\int \frac{x^3}{9-x^4}dx$ using u substitution and the log identity for integrating $x^{-1}$

Can somebody verify this solution for me? Thanks!!

---

Let $u=9-x^4$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=-4x^3$ and so $\frac{du}{-4x^3}=dx$. Thus we have:

$=\int \frac{x^3}{9-x^4}dx$

$=\int \frac{x^3}{u} \frac{du}{-4x^3}$

$=\frac{1}{-4} \int \frac{1}{u}du$

$=\frac{1}{-4} ln|u| + C$

$=\frac{1}{-4} ln|9-x^4| +C$

---

Okay, I just want to talk about something that I've been debating saying. Let's go back to this step:

$=\frac{1}{-4} \int \frac{1}{u}du$

Now, go look back and what I said the next equality sign was. Looks fine, right? But shouldn't it technically be:

$=\frac{1}{-4} (ln|u|+C)$

$=\frac{1}{-4} ln|u| - \frac{C}{4}$

See the difference? It's very subtle, but when you do it this way, which looks more correct, the constant of integration $C$ ends up with a $\frac{-1}{4}$ attached to it... It makes sense, since $\int \frac{1}{u} du = ln|u|+C$.

The point here is that the variable $C$ is called an *arbitrary* constant of integration for a reason. The point is we have no clue what it is, so if we multiply it by $\frac{-1}{4}$, we might as well just call it $C$ still because it can be anything anyway.... Note that this is not the case when we are doing a problem that gives "initial conditions", those problems where we solve for $C$ or plug something in for $C$, because then $C$ is no longer arbitrary.

Anyway, if your confused, that's okay, just kind of wanted to say this.

Comment: $C$ is not a constant, but any constant. It can be 100 or $\pi$ or 2.3344143534 . Any of these values will differentiate to $0$. In fact an integral is not one function but an infinity of functions all differing from one another by a constant.

Comment: FYI, regarding that $C$ is an *arbitrary* constant so you can still call it $C$ even if you multiply it by $\frac{-1}{4}$, a question asked just a few minutes ago of [Given the initial condition and ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3596796/602049) is closely related to this issue.

Comment: Well, you multiply an arbitrary constant by a constant, you get another arbitrary constant. Having said that, you can't call them both $C$ in a single sum. Maybe call the first one $c$ and the second $C$. Or $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it much easier: the chain rule and basic integration tells us that if we have a function $\;f(x)\;$ such that $\;\int f(x)\,dx= F(x)\;$ (meaning: $\;F(x)\;$ is a primitive of $\;f(x)\;$ , then for **any** differentiable funcion $\;g(x)\;$ we have that $\;\int g'
(x) f(g(x))\,dx=F(g(x))\;$ .This, of course, is just the principle for the substitution method, but we can make it shorter if we recognize the pattern.

In our case, observe that $\;(9-x^4)'=-4x^3\;$, so that we can write

$$\int\frac{x^3}{9-x^4}dx=-\frac14\int\frac{\overbrace{-4x^3}^{=(9-x^4)'}}{9-x^4}dx=-\frac14\log|9-x^4|+C (=\text{a constant})$$